# SSRS - Site Settings

Tags: reporting-services

I've been trying to figure this out and it's driving me crazy. I'm trying to restrict access to the Site Settings option on the home SSRS screen. Nothing I do as far as setting roles seems to make a difference. Everyone in the company who clicks on the link can edit the Site Settings. I am the only user as Content Manager and System Admin.

I don't know where to look next. Has anyone come across this before?

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEFQe.jpg

Comment: Don't forget that individual folders and reports can have their own security settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, only users who are members of the local administrators group can access a report server. A local administrator always has permission to fully manage a report server instance. So please check your company guys are in local administrators group.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014.aspx